# Maximum requests per second for Planner API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-planner

What is the maximum rate for requests per second for Microsoft Planner API (per app)?

To me, it starts limiting (returning 429) already at 10 requests per second.
The official document says: [unspecified](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/throttling-limits#tasks-and-plans-service-limits).

May I have an estimate?

Comment: I found out that limiting the requests to 5 a second (200ms between them) seemed to work. I never tried upping it since it was enough for my use case so if it breaks at 10 the limit might be somewhere in the middle. This was a couple of years ago though, I don't know if something changed in the meantime hence the comment and not an answer